# Have the Web API MediaTypeFormatter for x-www-form-urlencoded honor the DefaultValue attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, mediatypeformatter

Imagine I've got a model that looks like:

```
public class ToggleableResource
{
    [JsonProperty(DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Populate)]
    [DefaultValue(true)]
    public bool Enabled { get; set; }

    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

And I've got a controller that looks like:

```
public class FormatterDefaultsController : ApiController
{
    public ToggleableResource Post([FromBody] ToggleableResource resource)
    {
        return resource;
    }
}
```

If I submit a `POST` to `/api/formatterDefaults/` with `Content-Type: application/json` and a body of:

```
{ "Value": "some resource state" }
```

The value I get back looks like:

```
{
  "Enabled": true,
  "Value": "some resource state"
}
```

Which shows that `Enabled` is getting `true` from the `DefaultValue` attribute. However...

---

If I submit a `POST` again to `/api/formatterDefaults/`, but with `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and a body of:

```
value=some+resource+state
```

The value I get back is:

```
{
  "Enabled": false,
  "Value": "some resource state"
}
```

Is there any way I can get the [FormUrlEncodedMediaTypeFormatter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.formatting.formurlencodedmediatypeformatter(v=vs.118).aspx) (or whatever class is responsible) to honor the `DefaultValue` attribute and set `Enabled` to `true` when it is omitted from the request body?